# Android RoleManager, How to handle “Don't ask again” in while requesting?

Tags: android, role-manager

In Google [documention](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/role/RoleManager#isRoleHeld(java.lang.String)) there is no any information about, how to handle if user click “Don't ask again”. So if user click on it, in next time the app will not open a dialog for user. And in `onActivityResult` it returns just `RESULT_CANCELED`

Comment: did you find any solution? I'm trying to handle "Don't ask again" but there is no information in the android documentation.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't find any solution

Answer (score 0):

If the role is granted, the resultCode will be Activity.RESULT_OK, otherwise it will be Activity.RESULT_CANCELED. [source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/role/RoleManager#createRequestRoleIntent(java.lang.String))

The short answer is IS NOT POSSIBLE.